# Map an object by looping through alphabet

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to be able to loop through each letter of the alphabet and then if the StoreName in my json object matches that looped letter then map it to an li tag. I want to do this to every letter in the alphabet and if there is no match just display nothing.

Hope this makes sense.

for example:

This is what I have so far.

```
import { data } from './data/data';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(data);

  return (
    <div>
      {values.filter(store => store.storeName.startsWith('a'))
      .map((item, index) => (   
        <li key={index}>
          {item.storeName}
        </li>
      ))}

    </div>
  )
}
```

Json object:

```
export const data = [
    {
        storeId: 1, 
        storeName: 'addidas',
    },
    {
        storeId: 2, 
        storeName: 'axels',  
    },
    {
        storeId: 3, 
        storeName: 'blix',  
    },
    {
        storeId: 4, 
        storeName: 'benis',  
    },
    {
        storeId: 5, 
        storeName: 'clives',  
    },
];
```

I know i could filter and map each letter manually but there must be a way to loop through the alphabet and map?

example output:

A

- Addidas
- axels

B

- blix
- benis

c

- clives

d

So I want the letter to display and then the results for each item thats been looped that starts with that looped letter.

Comment: How does this differ from just iterating over all stores and create `li` elements for them. I mean, if you are going to loop over the whole alphabet, you will in the end have matched all stores, right? So why not just take them all?

Comment: I updated the question with desired output hope it helps more

Comment: Note that `<li>` is invalid child of `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

You could make a list of alphabet and map through that

```
import { data } from "./data/data";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

export default function Home() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(data);

  return (
    <div>
      {alphabet.split("").map((c) => {
        return (
          <>
            <p>{c}</p>
            {values
              .filter((store) => store.storeName.startsWith(c))
              .map((item, index) => (
                <li key={index}>{item.storeName}</li>
              ))}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit elated-fire-p7mkn]

Comment: Aww so simple when you think about it! Nice one

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to group your datapoints by initial letter. The algorithm you describe will work, but it's not the one I'd choose.

Here's how I would do it:

1. Sort all stores alphabetically
2. Iterate through the sorted stores, keeping track of the most recent initial letter

   - every time the current store's initial letter is different from the most recent, insert a grouping boundary (e.g. closing the previous `<li>` and opening a new one)

Finally, don't implement this within the JSX. It may not be the most complex algorithm in the world, but nobody will appreciate it if this data-preparation logic is intermixed with a bunch of display literals. Instead, work with the data as pure data. Bearing that in mind, "inserting a grouping boundary" just means changing which group you insert the store into.

---

Here's a run at the implementation. (I haven't tested it.)

```
function MyComponent( props ) {
    // group the stores by initial letter
    // produces a list of { initialLetter: 'A', stores: [ store1, store2, store3 ] }
    let prevInitialLetter = null
    let groupedStores = stores
    .sort(sort_storeName_alpha)
    .reduce(( groups, store ) => {
        let myInitialLetter = store.storeName.charAt(0)
        let belongsInNewGroup = myInitialLetter !== prevInitialLetter
        
        if(belongsInNewGroup) {
            // create a new group and add this store as its first member
            groups.push({ initialLetter: myInitialLetter, stores: [ store ] })
        } else {
            // add this store to the previous group
            groups[groups.length - 1].stores.push(store)
        }
        
        return groups
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <ol className="GroupedStores">
            {
                groupedStores.map(group => (
                    <li className="storeGroup" key={group.initialLetter}>
                        {group.initialLetter}
                        
                        <ol className="stores">
                            {
                                group.stores.map(store => (
                                    <li key={store.storeName}>
                                        {store.storeName}
                                    </li>
                                )
                            }
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                ))
            }
        </ol>
    )
}

// this is the crudest-possible text sort; depending on your needs,
// you may need to perform a locale-aware comparison
function sort_storeName_alpha = ( a, b ) => {
    if(a.storeName < b.storeName) return -1
    if(b.storeName < a.storeName) return 1
    return 0
}
```